# Using GWT widgets as like jQuery Plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

Can i use Google GWT Widgets like a jQuery Plugins?

For example:

```
Gwt('#a_css_selector').mywidget({some:'prefs'});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Reigel Generally people don't read help and FAQ's, specially engineers :-o

Comment: @Ashwin - at least I'm helping...

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're asking. Are you asking if you can use JQuery to interact with GWT widgets? (Yes you can). Are you asking if there's a GWT way of interacting with a page that's like JQuery? (Yes there is) Please be more specific, you'll get much better answers that way.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for something like [GQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). See the [Getting Started Guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: GQuery + JavaScript Native Interface [http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html