# GWT and JQuery cohabitation

Tags: java, jquery, gwt

I'll use GWT for my next project but I would like to use some of JQuery's very nice widgets,components (some datagrids).
Do you think is possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Ok I found an answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226959/using-gwt-widgets-as-like-jquery-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use GWT and JQuery in the same project.

Answer (score 2):

While you can, you are better off using [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/).  It's a port of JQuery to GWT.